# How to avoid duplicate records in database when using Automapper DTO to Entity

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, automapping

I am trying to `CREATE` or `UPDATE` multiple `Payment` for a single `Order`.
I would like to update the record if it exists in the database(`Primary Key Value is not the default value`), and I would like the record to be created if it doesn't exist in the database. For the moment, when I'm doing the creation, the Mapping adds a new order, by `Payment`, adds a necessary `Lines` and also adds the `Product` Item and the `Wallet` even if they already exist.

I use the `ReverseMap()` in all the DTO objects. here is an illustration

```
conf.CreateMap<Payment, PaymentDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.C_Order, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.C_Order))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.C_Wallet, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.C_Wallet))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DateOf, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DateOf))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Order, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Billing_Invoice))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Wallet, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CashWallet))
           .ReverseMap();
```

same logic is implement in OrderDTO, WalletDTO and so on.
How to tell AutoMapper not to create new record when this record do exists in the database ?
in the controller action, I tried to attach children to the context as follow `_context.Wallets.Attach(model.wallet);` but nothing seems to be working

here is the database diagram[image: digram]

Answer (score 0):

For the entities that exist in the database, either Attach() them to the DbContext, or set their State to Unchanged.

See [Entity Framework Add and Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)